# Iterators in JavaScript and remembering position

Tags: javascript, linked-list, ecmascript-6, iterator

This is an attempt to write a function `link` that creates a linked list from an array:

```js
function link(list) {
    let next = tail = null;

    for(let i = list.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {        
      const value = list[i];        
      next = { value, next };
    }

    let cursor = head = next;

    function* iterator() {
      while(cursor.next) {
        yield cursor;
        cursor = cursor.next
      }
      yield cursor;
    }

    return {
      [Symbol.iterator]: iterator,
      head,
      tail,
    };
}

console.log(...link([1,2,3,4]));
```

The iterator maintains a cursor to remember its position in the iteration.

This feels wrong and brittle.

Is it?

If so, how should the iterator be implemented here.

Comment: the structure youre generating feels wrong to me. i feel like you should get the code that consumes this structure reviewed and figure out a way to use a flat array instead.

Comment: I am walking from the right of the supplied list creating objects (list elements). Each time I create a list element I hold a reference to it and use that when populating the `next` property of the "previous" element. Can you explain which aspect feels wrong to you?

Comment: The structure you're building doesn't really add any value to the data. You're not really *doing* anything here except re-arranging data. Your final structure will require more than a simple loop to interate and there's no easy way to get a length from it without referring to the original object. Unless you require this structure for a web service or something the whole thing just feels unintuitive to me. Just my 0.02.

Comment: It's a linked list (albeit without insert, delete etc). Is it not?

Comment: What it is is more complicated than necessary. The question I'm asking is *why* is it a linked list? You may have a perfectly legitimate reason for doing what you're doing I just can't see the point on my end. Carry on..

Comment: Thank you. How would you simplify it? I welcome criticism and alternative implementations.

Comment: I would use recursion as someone else suggested. Sorry I don't have any specific suggestions for this piece of code, I'm just saying that if it were me personally I would explore the possibility of using native structures.

Comment: Your question was migrated from Stack Overflow to Code Review. On Code Review, we have a strict policy prohibiting the code in the question from being modified after an answer has been posted. I have rolled back Rev 3 → 1. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. You probably want to post a self-answer, if you have insight to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following recursive approach

```js
function link(list) {
    if(!list.length)
        return [];

    let [car, ...cdr] = list;
    return {
        car,
        cdr: link(cdr),
        [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
            yield this;
            yield *this.cdr;
        }
    }
}

ls = link([1, 2, 3, 4])

for (let t of ls)
    console.log(t.car)
```

Comment: I think this implementation is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

The number one problem with the code as originally written was that cursor was maintained at instance- rather than iterator-invocation level.

This is what "felt wrong" to me, although I could not articulate it at the time.

The following updated implementation moves the position of the cursor variable to solve this issue.

```js
function link(list) {
    let next = tail = null;

    for(let i = list.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {        
      const value = list[i];        
      next = { value, next };
    }

    function* iterator() {
      let cursor = this.head;
      while(cursor.next) {
        yield cursor;
        cursor = cursor.next
      }
      yield cursor;
    }

    return {
      [Symbol.iterator]: iterator,
      head: next,
      tail,
    };
}

var ll = link([1,2,3,4]);
console.log(...ll);
console.log(...ll);
```